# CRUD Class for PHP (Simple but will Allow Relational Data)

Tags: php, mysql, orm, crud

I am building a database of products and manufacturers. I already have the database layout done. I am looking for a simple CRUD class that will let me setup Manufacturers and Products and create the records quickly and easily. I have looked at ORM's but they all seem to be over kill for what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into CakePHP. The code generation (or scaffolding) will get you a working CRUD interface in a few minutes.

Comment: Even though I was trying to avoid a big framework CakePHP seems to have done the job. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Grocery CRUD, it is easy to use, has nice views with call backs. Might fit your needs. Check it out at http://www.web-and-development.com/grocery_crud/

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is fairly old, but I came across [this jQGrid + PHP component](http://azgtech.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/jqgrid-php-datagrid-component/), and for straight out install-and-go simplicity, it's hard to beat.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say with so few informations...

CouchDB + PHPillow if you don't neccessarily need SQL - works quite nice,
Zend_DB + (Sqlite|MySql|Postgress) otherwise ...

Comment: That even looks like over kill. I am really just looking for the form and queries to be generated. 

Or if someone has a good tutorial for an ORM I wouldn't mind learning just the documentation is a bit over my head from what I have found.

Answer (score 0):

Try Symfony. It's got good performance. Both Symfony and Doctrine (ORM used) have really good documentation sites.

http://www.symfony-project.org/